# Object does not support this propery or method IE & jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery and the cornerz plug in to get rounded corners on elements of the page without using images.

In IE7 and 8 it fails and I get this error:

"Object doesn't support this property or method"

on this lines:

```
  if($.browser.msie && settings.fixIE) {
      var ow = $$.outerWidth();
      var oh = $$.outerHeight();
```

Basically it complains about the outerWidth and outerHeight properties...

The cornerz demo page ([here](http://parkerfox.co.uk/labs/cornerz)) works perfectly on IE7 and 8 without throwing any error and it has got several examples...I do not know why this is happening

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you post you HTML and CSS for that element where the script blows up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using an old version of jQuery: instead of the 1.4.2 I went for the 1.2.6 and everything worked as expected

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing this line earlier in their script:

```
var $$ = $(this);
```

jQuery doesn't have a `$$` symbol, and I don't think cornerz does either (looking at the source), they're just using it as a local variable in a function. (See line 117 in the [cornerz source](http://github.com/weepy/cornerz/raw/master/cornerz.js).)